# Changing the content of a <select option> in Javascript but previous selection stays, why?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a simple script that checks a date and if "day chosen" == "tomorrow" then change a dropdown containing delivery options:

`Drop down:
0-When?(selected)
1-AM
2-PM`

If day = tomorrow then I remove in javascript the options:

`Drop down:
0-When?
2-PM(selected)`

The script:

```
// remove all options first
document.getElementById('inputheurelivraison').options.length = 0;
if (parseInt(datebits[2]) == parseInt(demain)){//remove am
  document.getElementById('inputheurelivraison').options[0] = new Option("WHEN?", 0, false, false);
  document.getElementById('inputheurelivraison').options[1] = new Option("PM", 2, true, true); // new Option(text, value, defaultSelected, selected)
  alert ("<? echo t(73); ?>");
}
else {//put am
  document.getElementById('inputheurelivraison').options[0] = new Option("WHEN?", 0, true, true);
  document.getElementById('inputheurelivraison').options[1] = new Option("AM", 1, false, false);
  document.getElementById('inputheurelivraison').options[2] = new Option("PM", 2, false, false);
}
```

The problem:

Let's say someone fill the form, then choose "AM" as the option and then change the date to "tomorrow", then my scripts run and remove the "AM" choice from the list and choose "PM" as "selected". When the user submit the form, the POST data is "AM" as selected...

Why? I chose "PM" and when I take a look at the HTML it says "PM" as "selected" so why does it not submit that value?

Thanks a bunch in advance

Joe

Comment: Your script is hard to read - can you add some line breaks to it to format it better?  Also, can you show us your HTML so we know what the javascript is acting against?

Comment: @Rock - when you have multi-line code samples don't use the ` character to format as code, instead select all of your code and press the `{}` formatting button (or just indent each line of code four spaces - and speaking of spaces, use space not tab). Don't include commented out code in a question either, unless it is somehow related to the question. I've formatted your post keeping the line breaks you intended.

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks... I was looking for that option but couldn't find it

Comment: And *please* store references to DOM objects and re-use them, you don't have to keep getting the element every time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to remove all options first, you can remove only the ones you don't want. Something like the following should be suitable (note storage of reference to DOM element so only get once):

```
var doIt = (function() {

  // Reference to removed option
  var removedOption;

  return function(s) {

    // Get reference to select once
    var select = document.getElementById('inputheurelivraison');

    if (parseInt(datebits[2]) == parseInt(demain)) {

      // Store reference to am option then remove it
      removedOption = select.options[1];
      select.removeChild(select.options[1]);

      // Make pm selected (it's now index 1)
      select.options[1].selected = true;

      // Debug?
      alert ("<? echo t(73); ?>");

    } else {
      // Replace removed option
      select.insertBefore(removedOption, select.options[1]);

      // Make first option selected
      select.options[0].selected = true;
    }

  }
}());
```

Alternatively you can move the unneeded option to a hidden select element.

The above is just a proof of concept example, there are many ways to skin the cat, the bottom line is you don't have to delete all the options and recreate the ones you want every time.

Comment: It should be noted that hiding option elements doesn't work in some browsers

Comment: Yeah, changed answer as IE 8 and lower don't play the game. :-( They do work with removed options though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. But I just found out what was the bug. I'll explain it in case it could help anybody else:

After checking if the "day" = "tomorrow" and changing the form, the script would then POST the data in AJAX to a PHP file. So here was the origin of the problem: I was asking my script to POST the `selectedIndex` of my dropdown instead of the `option[selectedIndex].value`of it. For this reason, my script was returning "AM" as the choice even if "PM" was selected because `selectedIndex` always start at 0, 1, 2 etc. and my `value` were AM=1 and PM=2.

So I changed:
`document.getElementById("inputheurelivraison").selectedIndex`

for:
`document.getElementById('inputheurelivraison').options[document.getElementById("inputheurelivraison").selectedIndex].value`

when sending the POST value in AJAX and now it's fine.

Hope nobody else makes this error :)

Comment: You know you can just use: `document.getElementById('inputheurelivraison').value` if all options have a value attribute or property?